# Handling button actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have 3 buttons named as : bw1 , bw2 and bw3

Simply, I want a specific action to be applied when one of these buttons is clicked using hidden.

Each button should only hide itself when clicked.

My problem is when bw3 is clicked, both bw3 and bw2 are hidden.  But when I click bw2, nothing wrong happened which means that the problem is in bw3 method.

I don't know what the problem is.  I traced the code many times but I could not find the solution.

```
- (IBAction)bw1:(id)sender {

    _lw1.hidden = NO;
    _bw1.hidden = YES;
}
- (IBAction)bw2:(id)sender {

    _lw2.hidden = NO;
    _bw2.hidden = YES;

}
- (IBAction)bw3:(id)sender {

    _lw3.hidden = NO;
    _bw3.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: check your xib, for _bw3, there are 2 IBAction set, bw2 and bw3..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment above

check your `xib`, for `_bw3`, there are 2 IBAction set, bw2 and bw3.

i.e. `- (IBAction)bw2:(id)sender` and `- (IBAction)bw3:(id)sender`

Hope it helps you..